# Solana/Anchor, what are the differences between types Account and ProgramAccount?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, account

https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0150---2021-09-07

`Account` is introduced to replace `ProgramAccount` and `CpiAccount`.

`ProgramAccount` checks if the account owner is the program itself. `CpiAccount` doesn't check the owner.

For `Account`, I am not sure if it checks or not.

```
Account<'info, Data>
Account<'info, TokenAccount>
Account<'info, Mint>
```

Looking at the source code, https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/686/files#diff-e5f86b0af3deae3466b401b3baebd9f2b742c410f4dfa09301d15786738a30c3L87, both `ProgramAccount` and `CpiAccount` has been replaced.

Looking at https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/686/files#diff-f439fa33af3b076c46b17fc06a938152ae629906934137106aa050dfac62c947 L25, L37, L66, L85, it's not clear whether it checks the owner or not.

Is there any information/reference I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, `Account` checks the owner program

https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/accounts/account/struct.Account.html

> Wrapper around AccountInfo that verifies program ownership and
> deserializes underlying data into a Rust type.
>
> Account checks that Account.info.owner == T::owner(). This means that
> the data type that Accounts wraps around (=T) needs to implement the
> Owner trait. The #[account] attribute implements the Owner trait for a
> struct using the crate::ID declared by declareId in the same program.
> It follows that Account can also be used with a T that comes from a
> different program.

Answer (score 0):

Account checks the followings:

- Account.info.owner == T: :owner()
- ! ( Account.info.owner == SystemProgram && Account.info.lamports() ==
  0 )